# Rails doesn't clean polymorphic _type field after relation is removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, polymorphic-associations, simple-form-for

I have Article model which can belong to either ServiceType or ServiceAddonType through polymorphic association (optional):

[image]

## Models

#### Article

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

#### ServiceType

```
class ServiceType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, as: :accountable
end
```

#### ServiceAddonType

```
class ServiceAddonType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, as: :accountable
end
```

## Article migration

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :articles, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :accountable, polymorphic: true, index: true, type: :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

---

## Problem:

When **adding** Article to ServiceType, everything works as expected. The polymorphic fields get the following values:

```
accountable_id: service_type.id
accountable_type: 'ServiceType'
```

After **removing** Article from ServiceType, the fields' values are:

```
accountable_id: nil
accountable_type: 'ServiceType'
```

Why? How can I fix this properly so that `accountable_type` would also be `nil` after removing the relation?
I made a `before_save` callback to Article model which would clean the field if `accountable_id` is `nil`, but this, as a matter of fact, doesn't seem to have any effect at all (`'ServiceType'` still remains as the _type value). I guess it might be because article update doesn't go through ActiveRecord at that point but through raw SQL-query when I remove it from ServicType. Therefore the callback never gets called. Anyhow I also feel there should be some better ways for achieving this.

---

### EDIT1:

#### Removing article from service_type:

**ServiceType form (slim-syntax):**
This gives me a box with list of articles and their checkboxes which are already assigned to service type. By unchecking them and clicking submit on the form I can remove the relation.

```
- if service_type.persisted?
    .square-box.small-12.medium-5
      - if service_type.articles.present?
        h5= t('article.assigned')
        = f.association :articles, collection: service_type.articles, as: :check_boxes, label: false
      - else
        = t('service_type.no_articles_assigned_yet')
```

**ServiceTypeController#update with strong_params:**

```
def update
  if @service_type.update(service_type_params)
    redirect_to service_types_path, notice: t(
      'service_type.successful_update',
      service_type_name: @service_type.name
    )
  else
    redirect_to edit_service_type_path(@service_type), alert: @service_type.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  end
end

private

def service_type_params
  params.require(:service_type).permit(:name, article_ids: [])
end
```

### EDIT2:

More complete version of my article-model with the callback I tested. The callback actually gets called when relation is **added** but doesn't get called when the relation is **removed**.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  default_scope { order(:name) }

  before_save :arrange_polymorphic_fields

  private

  def arrange_polymorphic_fields
    def arrange_polymorphic_fields
      !accountable_id.present? && self.accountable_type = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Rails log of removing the article from service-type:

```
Started PATCH "/service_types/acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-08 16:23:57 +0200
Processing by ServiceTypesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bbBWybKuXcwcYVZZqcL88VRY1U6puY9rz2TczyNEghlM+WIIf46lGtNYBk+sUITtLzhHWcNZl1FJL9s630rOgw==", "service_type"=>{"name"=>"Service-type 1", "article_ids"=>["", "8c2d53d8-9016-4e7b-85c8-d111797aa9d0", "84573dc7-c532-4055-a43d-ef5917cf1ec0", "0dc6da24-c221-4c24-9b22-c39b2f82a9d5", "f6a4dd0d-17bf-4bfd-9cc5-d871d23ad727", "25b25ed1-e4ae-43a6-87e7-f346def15aa5"]}, "id"=>"acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a"}
  ServiceType Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "service_types".* FROM "service_types" WHERE "service_types"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "service_types"."name" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Article Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" IN ('8c2d53d8-9016-4e7b-85c8-d111797aa9d0', '84573dc7-c532-4055-a43d-ef5917cf1ec0', '0dc6da24-c221-4c24-9b22-c39b2f82a9d5', 'f6a4dd0d-17bf-4bfd-9cc5-d871d23ad727', '25b25ed1-e4ae-43a6-87e7-f346def15aa5') ORDER BY "articles"."name" ASC
  Article Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."accountable_id" = $1 AND "articles"."accountable_type" = $2 ORDER BY "articles"."name" ASC  [["accountable_id", "acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a"], ["accountable_type", "ServiceType"]]
  SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "articles" SET "accountable_id" = NULL WHERE "articles"."id" IN (SELECT "articles"."id" FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."accountable_id" = $1 AND "articles"."accountable_type" = $2 AND "articles"."id" = '542803bf-73ee-496f-a7e7-077858925245' ORDER BY "articles"."name" ASC)  [["accountable_id", "acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a"], ["accountable_type", "ServiceType"]]
  ServiceType Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "service_types" WHERE "service_types"."name" = $1 AND ("service_types"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Service-type 1"], ["id", "acfe9618-69d4-4564-9ab5-65a50dc4b26a"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/service_types
Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
```

Comment: When you say "After removing Article from ServiceType", what are you performing as code to attain such ?

Comment: @Maxence - I added the corresponding #update action and view code in EDIT1

Comment: I didn't understand your code at first, especially the use of `f.association` and your strong parameters passing `article_ids` to `service_type` which is not a `service_type` parameter. Then realised you use SimpleForm. Unfortunately I am not familiar with SimpleForm. Maybe you can tag your question with SimpleForm so that users knowing the gem can help.. Though even if I am not familair of your ServiceTypeController#update action, the `before_save` hook should work (if this action is indeed responsible of handling the children associations). Maybe you can paste your  Article model.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I added the tags and also more complete view of article-model in EDIT2. Attached the #update action log entry also.

Comment: Found some new links. Seems like this really is a Rails problem and has been ongoing since 2008: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/974-attribute_type-is-not-set-to-null-if-dependent-nullify-is-specified-for-a-belongs_to-association and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28025

Answer (score 0):

That is strange it is not called when the relation is removed. Anyway your callback doesn't seem to do anything at the moment.

Maybe you can try changing the below:

```
def arrange_polymorphic_fields
    def arrange_polymorphic_fields
      !accountable_id.present? && self.accountable_type = nil
    end
  end
```

to

```
def arrange_polymorphic_fields
   unless self.accountable_id.present?
      self.accountable_type = nil
   end
end
```

And trying again to remove a relationship.

(Actually I see what you are trying to do with `!accountable_id.present? && self.accountable_type = nil` but I am not a great fan of mixing a conditional statement with actual assignment. I prefer writing dead simple code if not very concise.. And then we can go further is this is not where the problem comes from..)

Comment: Actually if this doesn't work, it is maybe the `SQL` access that bypasses the ActiveRecord. But this is very strange, I have never seen this. And I am not very sure SimpleForm would be responsible of this .. This would actually raise more questions than it solves.. In any cases SimpleForm does the job of removing association ..

Comment: Yes, despite it does the same, I tried with your code just in case, but the effect is the same. I test by adding `byebug` to the callback and the code doesn't stop at byebug's breakpoint when relation is removed. Therefore the callback isn't called at all and that's why I also think it's because the relation is removed somehow with not touching the `ActiveRecord` at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I am looking for but it solves my problem so far.

I assume this is a wider Rails problem because of [this old post](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/974-attribute_type-is-not-set-to-null-if-dependent-nullify-is-specified-for-a-belongs_to-association) and [this github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28025). I did try [`dependent: :nullify`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-dependent)) and for my Rails 5.1.6 it didn't work.

Therefore I came up with creating `ArticleConcern` and included it in `ServiceType` and `ServiceAddonType` models. Works as needed:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'active_support/concern'

module ArticleConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save -> { arrange_polymorphic_fields }
  end

  def arrange_polymorphic_fields
    Article.where(accountable_id: nil).where.not(accountable_type: nil).each do |a|
      a.update(accountable_type: nil)
    end
  end
end
```